# Maven POM dependencies to ivy.xml file

Tags: java, maven-2, ivy, dependency-management

Is there a maven plugin which i can use to convert the maven pom dependencies including transitive dependencies to an ivy.xml file?

Comment: Yes i am aware of the fr.jayasoft.ivy.ant Ant task, however i am looking for a maven plugin!

Comment: What's the usecase? I'm a big fan of ivy but spend most of my time integrating it with Maven technologies, not the other way around :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an Ant script

```
<project name="convertPomToIvy" basedir="." default="all"
  xmlns:ivy="antlib:fr.jayasoft.ivy.ant"
  xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

    <path id="antlib.classpath">
        <fileset dir="/path/to/ivy/libs" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef uri="antlib:fr.jayasoft.ivy.ant"
        resource="fr/jayasoft/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
        classpathref="antlib.classpath"
        loaderref="antlib.classpath.loader"/>

    <target name="convert">
        <ivy:convertpom pomFile="pom.xml" ivyFile="ivy.xml" />
    </target>

</project>
```

From [here](http://vafer.org/blog/20081030002755) or [here](http://stefan222devel.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-convert-maven-pomxml-into-ivy.html) (& probably elsewhere)

Answer (score 7):

I feel it is better to depend solely on apache as much as possible. So here is the ant build file which I ran successfully.

Just one line is required as specified in http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/use/convertpom.html.

```
<project
  name="convertPomToIvy"
  basedir="." default="all"
  xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="convert">
        <ivy:convertpom pomFile="pom.xml" ivyFile="ivy.xml" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: You might want to tell how you would run this.  Lots of people have heard of ant, but many of us have tried very hard to avoid having to learn or use it.  (I just got "BUILD FAILED
/Users/james/workspace/JavaSignatureParser/foo.xml:7: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:convertpom
Cause: The name is undefined." when I tried the obvious "ant -f foo.xml convert" - but I don't know or care much about ant...)

Comment: If you have to use Ivy, you have to use Ant. Teaching how to use Ant is beyond the scope here. AFA anyone who have used Ant, they would simply run the ant file from eclipse.

Comment: Follow the link I provided for org.apache.ivy.ant.

Comment: You can use ivy config files without using ivy itself.  sbt, for one, can read ivy files, so I've happily used ivy configurations without ever caring about ant.  You can also use ivy configurations in the ivy eclipse container just for doing dependency resolution, no ant involved.

Answer (score 1):

According to Ivy [1.3-RC1 Changelog](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/1.3-rc1.html)

> NEW: maven2 pom compatibility: most
>   resolvers are now able to handle m2
>   pom as project metadata and there is a
>   new convertpom task able to convert a
>   pom file to an ivy file (IVY-140)

This transformation is explained with moire details [in this blog post](http://vafer.org/blog/20081030002755).

I known it's not the maven, but the Ivy side, but anyway it seems to exist something, no ?
It "should" be possible to convert the code ([available on the web](http://www.koders.com/java/fidDC26FE961DDD92A4520A9D12FB9B9D913CDE5182.aspx?s=ivy+convertpom)) to a maven plugin to have this transformation directed by maven, if you wish so.