# How to compile jars from pom.xml with ant?

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar, build.xml

I used [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for project configure and [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for creating jars for some of my utility classes. When I create jars for my classes from **build.xml** , I got compile errors because some of third party jars were configure with maven and these jars were not exist in my project. If so , how to fix it ? Am I need to compile pom.xml from build.xml ? Or can I create jar file from **Maven** also ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html). They're designed just for that purpose.

Comment: after reading and testing entire your link , now I understand ... that was my answer. Thanks. By the way , **How can I import all dependecies in build.xml ?**.

Comment: now I am fine.. :D . pls check my answer , if you see any wrong settings or errors , pls correct me. Thanks for everythings.

Answer (score 6):

Now I have fully working with [Maven ant Task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html) . Now I can get all dependencies jar from ant build.xml. I can get them in two ways as below....

**1. Copy all jar files to specific location and add them in classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir="." xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
<path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="libs/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
<typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />

<artifact:pom id="mypom" file="pom.xml" />

<artifact:dependencies filesetId="mydeps" pomRefId="mypom" />

<target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with maven">
    <!-- Resolve dependencies -->
    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset">
        <pom file="pom.xml" />
    </artifact:dependencies>
    <!-- Copy all dependencies to the correct location. -->
    <copy todir="libs">
        <fileset refid="dependency.fileset" />
        <!-- This mapper strips off all leading directory information -->
        <mapper type="flatten" />
    </copy>
</target>

<property file="build.properties"/>

<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir = ".">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="resolve , compile">
    <description>Main target</description>
</target>
```

**2.Load pom.xml and refrence it as fileset**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir="." xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">

<path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="libs/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
<typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />
<property file="build.properties"/>

<!-- Load pom.xml for dependencies -->
<artifact:pom id="pomfile" file="pom.xml" />
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="mvn-dependencies" pomRefId="pomfile" />

<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset refid="mvn-dependencies" />
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>
    </javac>
</target>


<target name="main" depends="compile">
    <description>Main target</description>
    <echo> Finish Building for project - ${projectName}</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: I tried following the steps but was still unable to load the Maven dependencies in Ant. I am trying hard to figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i understood. You want to create a jar(which includes some of your utility classes)

When you take maven as a tool you don't have jars present in your project lib, they are present in your local repository (~/.m2) hence ant is not able find your third party jar.

doing it with maven would be one of the approach. find your solution here [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.U3byNvmSzVI)

CHEERS !

Comment: so you got your thing working, with the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). It is a dependency management designed to be used with Ant, and it is fully compatible with Maven repositories.

You will probably need to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715861/1512875) your pom.xml into ivy.xml (Ivy project descriptor) using [convertpom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/convertpom.html) Ant task, and then use Ivy Ant [tasks](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ant.html) (ivy:resolve, ivy:retrieve) to get all your third party jars from a maven repository.